# huffman archiver in the moder c++ + good architecture

Tags: c++

I've written my Huffman archiver in modern c++ (at the moment of writing), could you review it, please?

this is the main routine:

```
#ifndef ENCODING_HUFFMAN_ENCODING_H_
#define ENCODING_HUFFMAN_ENCODING_H_

#include <cassert>
#include <istream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <ostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "bit_io/bit_reader.h"
#include "bit_io/bit_writer.h"
#include "encoding/byte_streams_adapters/byte_aligned_bit_reader.h"
#include "encoding/byte_streams_adapters/byte_aligned_bit_writer.h"
#include "encoding/huffman_tree/huffman_tree_builder.h"
#include "letter/letter.h"

namespace {

constexpr bool kInnerNodeBitLabel = false;
constexpr bool kLeafNodeBitLabel = true;
constexpr bool kTurnLeftBitLabel = false;
constexpr bool kTurnRightBitLabel = true;
constexpr uint8_t kNumBitsForKeySize = 8u;

template <typename LetterType>
std::unordered_map<LetterType, std::vector<bool>> BuildCodesMap(
    huffman_tree::TreeNode<LetterType>* root) {
  assert(root);
  std::unordered_map<LetterType, std::vector<bool>> codes;

  if (root->isLeaf()) {
    codes[root->key_] = std::vector<bool>(1, kTurnLeftBitLabel);
    return codes;
  }

  struct NodeWithCode {
    huffman_tree::TreeNode<LetterType>* node;
    std::vector<bool> code;
  };

  std::stack<NodeWithCode> stack;
  stack.push(NodeWithCode{root, std::vector<bool>()});

  while (!stack.empty()) {
    const auto current = stack.top();
    stack.pop();

    if (current.node->isLeaf()) {
      codes[current.node->key_] = current.code;
      continue;
    }

    assert(current.node->isInner());

    {
      auto code = current.code;
      code.push_back(kTurnLeftBitLabel);
      stack.push(NodeWithCode{current.node->left_.get(), std::move(code)});
    }

    {
      auto code = current.code;
      code.push_back(kTurnRightBitLabel);
      stack.push(NodeWithCode{current.node->right_.get(), std::move(code)});
    }
  }

  return codes;
}

void ResetInputStream(std::istream& input) {
  input.clear();
  input.seekg(0);
}

}  // namespace

namespace encoding {
template <letter::LetterConfig Config>
class HuffmanEncoder {
 public:
  using LetterType = Config::LetterType;
  using TreeNode = huffman_tree::TreeNode<LetterType>;

  HuffmanEncoder(std::shared_ptr<Config> config,
                 std::shared_ptr<std::istream> input,
                 std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> output)
      : output_(std::make_shared<byte_adapters::ByteAlignedBitWriter>(
            std::move(output))),
        config_(std::move(config)) {
    auto letter_frequencies = CountLetterFrequencies(input);
    auto root = huffman_tree::BuildHuffmanTree<LetterType>(letter_frequencies);
    WriteTreeInPrefixForm(root.get());
    ResetInputStream(*input);
    WriteEncodedText(root.get(), std::move(input));
    output_->WriteFooter();
  }

 private:
  std::unordered_map<LetterType, uint32_t> CountLetterFrequencies(
      std::shared_ptr<std::istream> input) {
    auto letter_parser = config_->CreateParser(std::move(input));
    std::unordered_map<LetterType, uint32_t> letter_frequencies;
    while (letter_parser->HasNext()) {
      auto letter = letter_parser->Parse();
      ++letter_frequencies[*letter];
    }
    return letter_frequencies;
  }

  void WriteTreeInPrefixForm(TreeNode* root) {
    if (!root) {
      return;
    }

    WriteNode(root);

    WriteTreeInPrefixForm(root->left_.get());
    WriteTreeInPrefixForm(root->right_.get());
  }

  void WriteNode(TreeNode* node) {
    if (node->isInner()) {
      output_->WriteBit(kInnerNodeBitLabel);
    } else {
      output_->WriteBit(kLeafNodeBitLabel);
      config_->WriteSerialized(*output_, node->key_);
    }
  }

  void WriteEncodedText(TreeNode* root,
                        const std::shared_ptr<std::istream> input) {
    const auto codes_by_letter = BuildCodesMap(root);
    auto letter_parser = config_->CreateParser(std::move(input));
    while (letter_parser->HasNext()) {
      auto letter = letter_parser->Parse();
      if (!letter) {
        break;
      }
      assert(codes_by_letter.contains(*letter));
      for (const auto bit : codes_by_letter.at(*letter)) {
        output_->WriteBit(bit);
      }
    }
  }

  std::shared_ptr<std::istream> input_;
  std::shared_ptr<bit_io::BitWriter> output_;
  std::shared_ptr<Config> config_;
};

template <letter::LetterConfig Config>
class HuffmanDecoder {
 public:
  using LetterType = Config::LetterType;
  using TreeNode = huffman_tree::TreeNode<LetterType>;

  HuffmanDecoder(std::shared_ptr<Config> config,
                 std::shared_ptr<std::istream> input,
                 std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> output)
      : input_(std::make_shared<byte_adapters::ByteAlignedBitReader>(input)),
        output_(std::move(output)),
        config_(std::move(config)) {
    auto root = ReadTreeInPrefixForm();
    WriteDecodedText(root.get());
  }

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> ReadTreeInPrefixForm() {
    const std::optional<bool> bit = input_->ReadBit();
    if (!bit) {
      return nullptr;
    }

    if (*bit == kLeafNodeBitLabel) {
      auto node_key = config_->ReadSerialized(*input_);
      if (!node_key) {
        return nullptr;
      }
      return std::make_unique<TreeNode>(std::move(*node_key), 0, nullptr,
                                        nullptr);
    }

    assert(*bit == kInnerNodeBitLabel);
    auto node = std::make_unique<TreeNode>(LetterType(), 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    node->left_ = ReadTreeInPrefixForm();
    node->right_ = ReadTreeInPrefixForm();
    return node;
  }

  void WriteDecodedText(TreeNode* root) {
    if (!root) {
      return;
    }

    auto* current_node = root;
    for (auto bit = input_->ReadBit(); bit; bit = input_->ReadBit()) {
      if (current_node->isInner()) {
        if (*bit == kTurnLeftBitLabel) {
          current_node = current_node->left_.get();
        } else {
          assert(*bit == kTurnRightBitLabel);
          current_node = current_node->right_.get();
        }
      }

      if (current_node->isLeaf()) {
        config_->Write(*output_, current_node->key_);
        current_node = root;
      }
    }
  }

  std::shared_ptr<bit_io::BitReader> input_;
  std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> output_;
  std::shared_ptr<Config> config_;
};

}  // namespace encoding

#endif  // ENCODING_HUFFMAN_ENCODING_H_
```

The all code is here:
https://github.com/dbezhetskov/huffman

I really try to do my best to write it clear, readable, and enjoyable, hope you will find it pleasant to read.

Answer (score 2):

## This should be a function, not a class

Your `class HuffmanEncoder` only has a public constructor, and it does everything. That means the whole `class` can just be replaced by a single function that does what the constructor did. This also means that there is no reason to pass the parameters to this function as `std::shared_ptr`s. Your function should look like this:

```
void HuffmanEncode(Config &config, std::istream &input, std::ostream &output)
{
    ...
}
```

The `private` member functions should now become `static` functions that you pass references to `config`, `input` and `output` as necessary.

## Possible issues resetting the input stream

I see that you scan the input first to build a frequency table, and then reset it so you can read it again and produce the Huffman-compressed output. However, be aware that there might be issues with this:

- The input stream might not have been at the beginning when you start building the frequency table.
- The input stream might not support seeking (for example, if the input is not a regular file but a socket, pipe, or `std::cin`).

I see two options to deal with this:

1. Record the current position of the stream before starting to build the frequency table, and seek back to that position for the second pass. Check whether the stream is still good after the call to `seekg()`, and return an error somehow otherwise.
2. Split this function into two: one to build a frequency table, and a second to encode a given input based on the provided frequency table. This allows the caller to deal with positioning the input stream, and frees your functions from that responsibility.

## Ensure you check for errors while reading from and writing to the streams

What happens if `ReadBit()` or `Write()` encounters an error while reading from or writing to a stream? The return value of `ReadBit()` suggests to me that it would return `std::nullopt` in case of an error. If so, then your code considers that equivalent to having reached the end of the input. However, you should ensure you properly propagate errors, as ignoring it might cause problems later on. Consider throwing exceptions in case of read or write errors.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I can't agree with the first point because 1) in case of function I need to pass config and input stream parameters there & here and it make the code is less readable. 2) HuffmanEncoder owns input and so, if your inner code want to transfer or share ownership it can be done. With references code becomes dangerous because we need to provide guarantee that the caller will make parameters alive.

Comment: As for point 1, that can be argued. But for point 2: there should be no transfer of ownership; after Huffman encoding is done, nothing you called should still hold ownership. And the caller is suspended while the constructor is running, so the parameters are guaranteed to be alive during that time.